# Transform data into excel from deeply nested json

Tags: python, json, excel, dataframe

i am new to python, fetching data from web url into json format and trying to convert nested json into data frame ,after that dump into excel. But i am not getting the expected output.

JSON:

```
"balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly": {
  "balanceSheetStatements": [
    {
      "intangibleAssets": {
        "raw": 1557545000,
        "fmt": "1.56B",
        "longFmt": "1,557,545,000"
      },
      "capitalSurplus": {
        "raw": 2197934000,
        "fmt": "2.2B",
        "longFmt": "2,197,934,000"
      }
    },
    {
      "intangibleAssets": {
        "raw": 1547187000,
        "fmt": "1.55B",
        "longFmt": "1,547,187,000"
      },
      "capitalSurplus": {
        "raw": 2197934000,
        "fmt": "2.2B",
        "longFmt": "2,197,934,000"
      }
    }
  ],
  "maxAge": 86400
}
```

expected output:

[image]

have tried below code:

```
#f = open('file.json')
data1 = json.load(open('file.json'))
print("data1",data1)
data = data1 ['balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly']
print("dftyp",data)
data1 =pd.json_normalize(data['balanceSheetStatements'])
#data1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(['balanceSheetStatements'], data1.columns))
print("data1",data1)
data1.to_excel("output\\DATAFILE4.xlsx")
```

output is :

[image]

How to make json standard and convert into e.xcel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Turn the nested list into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data1['balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly']['balanceSheetStatements'])

# Extract the value of 'raw' as columns
df['intangibleAssets'] = [i['raw'] for i in df['intangibleAssets']]
df['capitalSurplus'] = [i['raw'] for i in df['capitalSurplus']]

# Export to CSV
df.to_csv('your_file_name.csv')
```

Edit: Generalize the list comprehension for more columns.

```
def get_raw_for_cols(df, col_names):
   for name in col_names: 
      df[name] = [i['raw'] if isinstance(i, dict) else i for i in df[name]]
   return df
```

Comment: its working but i have one  doubt ,suppose i get n number of columns that contain "raw" field data. so manually i have to mention all n number of columns? currently in my code only two columns(intangibleAssets, capitalSurplus) are available but some time its more then two. so how to handle that.

Comment: You can generalize the above list comprehensive and create a function to apply to all the columns that have `raw` as keys. See my edited answer above.

Comment: @ Freda Xin -as you mentioned have used code like below but getting "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable" for few columns data. *code*-  ```data1 = json.load(open('file.json'))
df = pd.DataFrame(data1['balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly']['balanceSheetStatements'])

col_names = df.keys()
print("column",col_names)

def get_raw_for_cols(df, col_names):
   for name in col_names:
    print("df", name)
    df[name] = [i['raw'] for i in df[name]]
    print("df1", df)
   return df

df1 = get_raw_for_cols(df, col_names)
df1.to_csv('output\\DATAFILE6.csv')```

Comment: For the input of the function, you need to provide a list of column names that contains 'raw', not all of the columns. The function cannot be applied to columns of float or int type. 
If you do `df.info()`, you should see the columns types.

Comment: all columns contain raw. df.info() output -```<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 30 columns):
 #   Column                   Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------                   --------------  ----- 
 0   intangibleAssets         4 non-null      object
 1   capitalSurplus           4 non-null      object
 2   totalLiab                4 non-null      object
 3   totalStockholderEquity   4 non-null      object
 4   shortTermInvestments     3 non-null      object``` function failed on "shortTermInvestments"     column

Comment: column contain similar data like other columns -```"shortTermInvestments": {
  "raw": 95000,
  "fmt": "95k",
  "longFmt": "95,000"
},```

Comment: I see. the `shortTermInvestments` has a null value in it, which is causing this error. I updated the function in my answer to deal with null. Try it now.

Comment: df[name] = [i['raw'] if isinstance(i, str) else i for i in df[name]] like is not working ,for raw it highlighted ```Expected type 'union[int,slice]' got str instead```

Comment: showing output like dict- ```df1                                     intangibleAssets  \
0  {'raw': 1557545000, 'fmt': '1.56B', 'longFmt':...   
1  {'raw': 1547187000, 'fmt': '1.55B', 'longFmt':...   ```

Comment: The error should give the clue: instead of ` isinstance(i, str)`, it should be ` isinstance(i, dict)`. I edited my answer. Try now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251245/discussion-between-freda-xin-and-alia).